# rspec check presence custom link href into head

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I need check presence custom link into `head` tag.
i found many examples where need to set some text to `link` tag
such as

```
should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user))
```

but i need check only attr href exists

my code:

```
it 'custom href presence to head tag' do
  within('head') do
    link = page.find(:xpath, "//link[@href='#{my_custom_url}']")
    ...
  end
end
```

but i see error `Capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find css "head"`

How i can implement this?

Comment: did you try `link = page.find(:xpath, "/head/link[@href='#{my_custom_url}']")` without a `within`?

Comment: yes, looks like need to add , visible: false